# Unable to find main (Error) while launching Unity from Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to launch UnityPlayerActivity on button click. But its throwing up an error as "Unable to find main".

In Manifest,

```
<activity
        android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
        android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.CARDBOARD" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
            android:value="true" />
    </activity>
```

I am launching using the below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, UnityPlayerActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just building the armeabi-v7a build will work. But if you are trying to build other builds like x86 or universal apk, then you are goind to get this sort of error.

So, in gradle specify to build only armeabi-v7a apk.

```
splits {

    // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
    abi {

        // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
        enable true

        // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
        // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.

        // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
        reset()

        // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
        include "armeabi-v7a"
    }
}
```